# How can I return derived fields by using TFS 2013 query

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports, tfs-query, tfs-2013

We have an Application on Reporting on TFS items. I am using Query against TFS and fetching the tfs items.

I am using below query

```
"Select [ID], [State], [Title], [Work Item Type], [Severity] " +
 "From WorkItems " +
 @"Where ([Area Path] Under 'MYPATH') " +
 "AND [Work Item Type] In ('Bug', 'Task', 'Issue')");
```

Now I want to return new field which tells if the workItem was ever Regression or not.

I would like to change query some thing like

```
"Select [ID], [State], [Title], [Work Item Type], [Severity], [IsRegression] " +
 "From WorkItems " +
 @"Where ([Area Path] Under 'MYPATH') " +
 "AND [Work Item Type] In ('Bug', 'Task', 'Issue')");
```

IsRegression Should be True if it wasever Regression or False if it was ever not a regression

How can I write query for this?